# TP-Link TL-WR740N stops recognizing the WAN connection

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I'm trying to install the TP-Link TL-WR740N to route a Motorola SBV5122 modem. After I setup the cables, all the lights are okay. When I start the installation wizard, the WAN light turns off on both gadgets and I get a message saying there's no WAN connection.

I've tried installation through CD and through the router's address and both give me the same problem. I think it might be an issue with the modem or a restriction imposed by the ISP.

Has anyone had a similar problem or can help me?

Answer (score 1):

[***Print this answer for reference.***](https://superuser.com/revisions/1074000/1)

Ensure you have the basics down by starting over and double checking the hardware part:

- **Disconnect all** power and ethernet cables from all network related devices for a clean start.
- **Power on the modem and check the LEDs** to make sure that it has booted and is not updating.
- **Reset your router** using the [30-30-30](http://compnetworking.about.com/b/2009/03/11/the-30-30-30-hard-reset-rule-for-routers.htm) approach so you get another clean start.
- **Check the ethernet ports** of both devices for oxidated, deflected or bent pins
- **Insert the ethernet cables**, give them a bit of care instead of just inserting it too loose or so:

  > ***WARNING:*** The cables and connectors are designed for plug-and-play, be gentle and careful!

  - Use a cable tester if you have any, or have your cables tested by a network technician. Given the low cost of them, just buying new ones is also an option.
  - Insert it as deep as reasonably possible and disallow it from falling back out, don't force it
  - Bent it very slightly such that it touches; however, do not apply pressure as to not bent pins
  - Bent the plastic a slight bit for firmer grip; however, do not apply pressure as it breaks easily

You can then continue with the software:

- It is important that you update your router to the **latest firmware** as soon as you are able to; if needed, do another 30-30-30 reset after it if there are further problems with it.
- **Configure the wizard correctly**, double check that you are sure that what you fill in is correct.
- **Check the WAN configuration and WAN status pages** to see what exactly it does(n't) do.
- **Turn the router off and on again** to ensure it has loaded the configuration changes.

If it still doesn't work, take note of the following details
such that you can provide them for further diagnosis to your ISP, to us or others:

- What does the WAN status page say?
- What is filled in in the WAN configuration page?
- What exactly do you fill in in the wizard?
- When exactly do the WAN lights go off?

Comment: So, I've done all you said and it still doesn't work. I get a message at the WAN status page saying there's no WAN connection. I don't fill anything in the wizard, when I start, it stops due to the lack of WAN connection.

Comment: @EmílioB There is no such thing as "don't fill anything in" because you need to pick a choice. Assuming "auto-detect" to be the default and not working, you might want to pick "Dynamic IP" (most ISPs) or contact your ISP for more information

Comment: I pick auto-detect and it stops after some seconds, telling me there's now WAN connection.